# How to make a generic typed class serializable?

Tags: java

The usecase is the following, I have a generic class as follows:

```
public class Test<T> implements Serializable {
private T testObject;
 .....
}
```

With sonarLint off course complaining about the field testObject should be made either transient or serializable.

If I would make the required/proposed change as follows:

```
public class Test<T extends Serializable> implements Serializable {
    private T testObject;
     .....
    }
```

Although if I want to make use of this Generic Test class, then I can't use it together with interface types like for example a List interface, because a List is of course not Serializable.

This doesn't compile, but is in my opinion the preferred way programming to the interface.

```
public Test<List<String>> doSomething() {
}
```

This compiles, but is actually not what I want...

```
public Test<ArrayList<String>> doSomething() {
}
```

So, not sure what the answer to my question is.... should I ignore the SonarLint warning or is there a different way to solve/bypass this?

Comment: "`ArrayList<List<String>> doSomething()`" what has this got to do with your `Test` class? Do you mean `Test<ArrayList<String>>`?

Comment: "is there a different way to solve/bypass this?" it very much depends on what you are trying to do/"how generic" you really need it to be (as in, do you need it for any T, or is there some small handful of Ts that you need).

Comment: You should probably find a different way to solve your serialization needs, but if you insist on using java's serialization mechanism (which has all sorts of problems), next best thing is to fully understand its many, many nuances. Once you know about them, you can also figure out what that warning is about, adjust accordingly, and _then_ ignore the warning.

Comment: One thing to point out about Sonar's warning: I'm pretty sure that it wouldn't warn you about a `Test<ArrayList<NonSerializableThing>>` being non-serializable - in part, because it would be serializable, if the list is null or empty. So, the impression of safety conveyed by the warning is a bit misleading.

Comment: @AndyTurner I corrected indeed the ArrayList<List<String>> doSomething() part, was just a typo.
Further the code should be able to serialize all T's. This makes me wondering if I could just ignore the warning, given the fact that if my concrete class (~T) implements the Serializable class, wouldn't that be enough then?

Comment: @rzwitserloot what do you mean by all sorts of problems with the java serialization mechanism?

Answer (score 3):

An object that holds a reference to a non-Serializable object cannot be serialized via the default serialization algorithm. For your particular case, there is no type-safe way to engage custom serialization.  You therefore have only three main options:

1. Do not modify your original code, and accept that it ***lies*** when it declares itself `Serializable`.  If it actually matters to you that the class be `Serializable` -- that is, you plan to serialize instances -- then this creates a non-negligible failure risk, but you could get away with it if, in practice, the `testObject` member always is serializable.  This is effectively the strategy employed by `java.util.ArrayList` and some other serializable standard library classes.
2. Do not make your class `Serializable`.  Then the immediate problem goes away, but of course, instances are even more not default-serializable.  That may not work for you.
3. Implement the proposed change you describe, with `T extends Serializable` (or `extends` some other serializable type).  This is the type-safe alternative.  It avoids risk of serialization failure insomuch as that is within your class's control.  The cost is as you describe -- the type parameter will exclude types that are not serializable.  For the specific case of `List`s, you could instead use one of the serializable `List` implementations in place of the `List` interface, but you'll have to determine how well that works for you, technically and stylistically.

We can't tell you which of those is best for your particular purposes.  You'll have to decide that for yourself.

Comment: We are currently applying option 1 in our codebase, because all testObjects are indeed Serializable, but you miss out on type safety compilation warnings in this way.
btw. Is an object skipping serialization in total when it holds a reference to a non-Serializable object?

Option 2 is not an option open to discuss and option 3 is in my opinion also not preferable because I prefer my methods to return an interface type (List) instead of a real implementation (ArrayList)

Comment: @RIJA, if you attempt to serialize an instance of your class when it holds a reference to a non-serializable object then a `java.io.NotSerializableException` will be thrown.  I'm unsure whether you will consider that an advantage or a disadvantage.

Comment: @RIJA, I understand and appreciate your stylistic preference to operate in terms of interfaces instead of concrete classes.  In this case, that is at odds with compile-time type checking.  You'll need to decide which is more important to you.